# Leading 0 has been cut off in joint table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, however in t2 the data source has missed out the zeros at the beggining of some of the rows. This is just the way the data is when I receive it and there is nothing I can do to change it.

I want to be able to join these table but as you can see the leading zero has been cut off in the t2

Is it posible to put a condition that is able to join these still?

```
t1      t2
01234   1234
t3249   t3249
432234  432234
2332    2332
04532   4532
1234    1234
```

Comment: Query - some of the values in t1 do not have a leading zero either.  Are you sure 01234 should actually match 1234 in t2?

Comment: Are the numeric-only values *only* integers?

Comment: hi paddy, yeah I had to check this a few times but yeah i am sure 01234 and 1234 are two seperate IDs in t1, it's not a good set up but i've been asked to help out with this

Comment: @AaronBertrand no, they can be numeric or alphanumeric

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronBertrand could you explain

Comment: @neeko He asked if the values that don't have alpha characters in them, are they only integers or could they be something else as well?

Comment: As in are they integers or are they ever decimal numbers, also could your alphanumerics be things like `2d2` which can actually be misinterpreted as a decimal?

Comment: @TTeeple thanks for your reply, sorry i misunderstood, they are only integer, i have checked and all other values in t2 look correct except for when they are meant to start with a 0

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(t1,'0',' ')),' ','0') = t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @T table (t1 varchar(10), t2 varchar(10))

insert into @t values
('01234',   '1234')
,('t3249',   't3249')
,('432234',  '432234')
,('2332',    '2332')
,('04532',   '4532')
,('1234',    '1234')

select t1, right('000'+t2,len(t1)) t2 from @t
```